# Type Mismatch : cannot convert from Int to ResultSet using oracle sql developer. ExecuteUpdate

Tags: java, resultset

I can't add items to the database because of this apparently.
Not putting the entire code, hope you can understand.

```
import java.sql.Connection/Driver/ResultSet/SQLException/Statement;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Statement st = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try(Connection conn = everything right here)){
            if(conn != null) {
                System.out.println("Success conn!");
                String query = "INSERT INTO students (id, nome) VALUES (1, 'College Name')";
                st = conn.createStatement();
                rs = st.executeUpdate(query);
```

Giving me type mismatch: can't resolve `int` to `ResultSet` in

```java
rs = st.executeUpdate(query);
```

```
                // continuation of above code
                while(rs.next()) {
                    System.out.println("\nRegistro");
                    System.out.println("id: " + rs.getInt(1));
                    System.out.println("nome: " + rs.getString(2));
                }
                rs.close();
                st.close();
                conn.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the Javadoc for `Statement.executeUpdate`,

Comment: Method [executeUpdate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String)) returns the number of rows affected as an `int`. In your case that will be 1 (one) if the INSERT succeeded. The error message is telling you that you cannot assign an `int` to a `ResultSet`. Did you think that `executeUpdate` returns the inserted row?